# what is the asterisk sign in array mean?

Tags: ruby

The two lines has the same meaning in Ruby, I saw it from somewhere
if I set a=1 b=10, it should give me the number in 1~10,
But I don't know why there needs * in front  of `a`

```
(a..b).to_a.sample
[*a..b].sample
```

Answer (score 2):

`*a..b` Doesn't *just* call `Enumerable#to_a`, (it does call it, but that is just a side effect of its real purpose) the unary `*` operator in ruby expands `Enumerable`s into containing `Array`s. Like this:

```
[*[1,2]]
# => [1, 2]
```

This has been implemented on enumerables also, but in order for it to work, Ruby has to call `.to_a` on it first to "cast" the enumerable into an `Array`.

Comment: Yes. that's how I also told. What's more there ?

Comment: I think if I remember your answer correctly, it states that the `*` calls `to_a`, but then if that's all it's doing then, what should `[*((a..b).to_a)]` be?

Comment: That's not the thing. `*` apply `to_a`.. that's it. Rest all you are seeing.. you are just mimicing what we are seeing.. That's not the techincal reason. One thing I couldn't answer, from where `#each` does come. If you write `[*[1,2]]`.. this just a `#to_a` method. Nothing. If anything more.. That's not present in your answer.

Comment: @ArupRakshit probably `Enumerable#to_a` calls `each` to enumerate the elements

Comment: While you are correct that the *behaviour* of `[*x]` for any enumerable `x` is equivalent to `x.to_a` this does not answer what `*x` is doing (because if `*x` was *just* calling `to_a` then why do we need to wrap it in square brackets? Because it is splatting and requires a *containing `Array` instance* that is what my answer adds (the clarification that a containing array instance is required).

Comment: @asQuirreL Splat operator always requires a context because is interpreted differently by its context. At the left or right side of an assignment or as an argument passed to proc/method. So `*x` won't work solitary. In an expression `[*x]` which is an Array constructor it gets context of method `Array.new` and passed to as an argument `x.to_ary`.

Comment: Mhmm, this need for a context is what I am trying to convey.

Comment: It doesn't pass the argument as an array, it passes the array's elements as separate arguments.

Comment: @Stefan In fact, the splat operator builds elements list of the object. At objects responding to `to_a` it uses `each` upon resulting array, otherwise just `inspect` method.

Answer (score 2):

`*` turns the range into an argument list:

```
[1..10]  #=> [1..10]                          (array with a single element)
[*1..10] #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  (array with 10 elements)
```

It's like passing the range's elements as multiple arguments to [`Array::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D), as opposed to passing the range's elements as an array:

```
[(1..10).to_a] #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]  (nested array)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called splat operator (see spec for it: https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/language/splat_spec.rb).

`*a..b` converts range to array elements (with `#to_a` method) and assigns to outer array (it doesn't create inner array if you splat inside array already).